# How to fix phpMyAdmin with PHP 7.2 on RHEL7?

Tags: redhat, rhel7, phpmyadmin

I've upgraded PHP from 5.4 to PHP 7.2 on a vanilla web server running RHEL7. The source of the PHP7.2 is RHSC using `yum`.  I've also installed the standard supporting libraries for this version, including `rh-php72-php-fpm`, and started it as a service.

I do *not* access the web server from localhost, but over the web. For now, I have "Require all granted" in `phpMyAdmin.conf` (will lock down when I get things working again).

This server has *SELinux* enabled - but this has always been the case and I do not think *SELinux* is the cause of this problem (for one thing: disabling *SELinux*  makes no difference).

When PHP 7.2 is enabled for the Apache 2.4 web-server, *phpMyAdmin* stops working (the rest of the site looks OK).

I installed *phpMyAdmin* ages ago using `sudo yum install phpmyadmin` - and haven't touched it since.

The error message on the web page is "File not found". This is different from a regular 404-response (i.e. requesting a file that really does not exist).  The screen dumps below shows the difference.  The first is when requesting `/phpmyadmin` (where `index.php` exists), the second when requesting `/phpmyadmin/zzzz` (which does not exist). Requesting `.html`-files that exists in this directory works.

[image: Two screens]

The error messages in the `error_log` for Apache are:

> […] [proxy_fcgi:error] […] […] AH01071: Got error: 'Primary script unknown\n'
>   […] [autoindex:error] […] […] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

I *believe* these error message indicates that Apache does not recognize `index.php` as a legitimate script file.

However, I've checked, and the configuration for Apache says:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Apache has no problem loading `index.php` from any other directory that is part of the web site.

My Apache configuration is *mostly* the one that ships with RHEL7. To get the configuration file for PHP-FPM loaded, I've put the following at the end of `httpd.conf`:

```
#Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
<IfModule proxy_module>
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
</IfModule>
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

The stuff within the `IfModule` conditional are not part of the version that ships with RHEL7.  There are no other changes to `httpd.conf`.

I've restarted Apache (and even rebooted the web server), but so far, no luck - PHP 7.2 works fine, but not for *phpMyAdmin*.

If anyone has seen this before, and knows the solution, great!  But also suggestions for how to debug this will be welcome.

Comment: What is your Apache configuration? You have only included one small (and not relevant) part of it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Expanded question with the information you requested. Please indicate if other files than `httpd.conf` are relewant.

Comment: OK, I see what's going on. Your URL path /phpmyadmin refers to the directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin, rather than the directory /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin, presumably because you're using RPM packages for phpMyAdmin. I know how to deal with this on nginx, but I have no idea about Apache with php-fpm (I abandoned Apache over a decade ago and haven't looked back). Someone should be along soon with more significant help.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thanks! Your comment prompted me to use a symlink rather that to rely on the alias preset by RedHat in `phpMyAdmin.conf` - and lo and behold: It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a workaround: If I create a symbolic link from my webroot to `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin`, *phpMyAdmin* becomes available on that path. I.e. the following command in the webroot makes *phpMyAdmin* available using the path `/phpmyadmin`:

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/ phpmyadmin
```

I've no idea if this is the *canonical* solution to this problem, so please feel welcome to provide alternative answers - but at least this symlink works.